# Designing and loading levels in a game

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, levels

I'm very new to game programming so excuse my very vague questions :P

I've begun working on a 2D game using OpenGL on the iPhone as a means to teach myself game programming. I've come to the point where I've written an engine, gotten things like collision detection working and other animations but now I need to actual start on creating something sort of playable and my first big question is on levels. For my project I'm going to be using a [Tiled map](http://www.mapeditor.org/) for the levels and my question is: How would I go about "designing" a level? And by this I mean, how do programmers know at what point in a map should certain enemies come into play? How can they specify certain things in the level that will happen? Overall is there a methodology for designing a level (from programming perspective) and be able to load it to use it? How do game programmers do this? I know of course there is an enemy AI part to this so that I of course wouldn't be pre-writing each and every movement for every enemy but at least basically knowing when each one should come into play and things of that sort though? Thanks again for any help and again I'm sorry if my questions are too vague because I'm just starting out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with the old-fashioned way: make mobs stationary.  Your map data can contain mobs, where they are located, what type they are, and how they move.  A carefully designed map can make the game very challenging and fun.

For AI's, typically a hybrid of multiple algorithms will be necessary.  Say if you're doing something like a single player free-mode StarCraft, the AI can be combination of heuristics (i.e. pre-cooked strategy such as flooding player base with overwhelming power, creating second base) and min-max algorithm decision (i.e. in an encounter, take out the most threatening unit as you would do in chess).  That is an interesting topic and is also the foundation of many fellow programmers'/scientists' career.

Answer (score 3):

Well its usually something you do to suit your needs.  There is no one right way.

For a 3D platformer game I worked on years ago I designed the editor and game logic.  The game logic was all a C++ hierarchy and each object had the ability to pass messages to other objects.  To activate a lever which opened a door I would simply set up a simple "trigger zone" which was a logic object in itself that, simply, checked if the user was inside the sphere (As the level was organised into certain "zones" I needn't check triggers that weren't in my current zone).  The trigger would then activate the lever (and this would start the animation).  The lever was then set up to activate the door once it had been pulled.  As any object could be a trigger it was simple to chain the triggers together.  I could even assign triggers to certain points.  Such as AnimationBegin, AnimationEnd, after a certain time or it could be keyed to a specific key frames in the animation.  As each object could have triggers like this it was easy to design the editor to allow you to select a trigger event and then set which object was activated when the trigger occurred.  Of course these trigger could just happen keyed to an animation which allowed me to do things like synchronising object movement for more nasty traps ...

This is only one method and it worked beautifully for what we needed it for.  There are many many different ways to approach this problem.  No one way is correct so your best bet is to read up on things like "Game Logic" and "game object behaviours".  More to the point you need to figure out what sort of interactions you are after and think about the state transitions that you will require.  Counter-intuitively I've always found its significantly more complicated to design the frame work than it is to write the actual logic.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [this](http://www.gamedev.net/) page, there are a lot resources for game developers